# Player 1 doesn't get his turn in game of Nim

Tags: java

I am developing a game of nim which will be played by 2 people. Problem is that after 1 iteration, it keeps switching to player2 even though it is not his turn.Player 1 gets completely ignored until the end of the game. Here is my code:

```
    int A = 3;
    int B = 4;
    int C = 5;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Player 1 name :");
    String player1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Player 2 name :");
    String player2 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("  A: " + A + "  B: " + B + "  C: " + C);

    do {

        System.out.println(player1 + " choose a pile : ");

        String choose = input.nextLine();

        if (choose.equals("A")) {
            System.out.println("How many to remove from pile A:");

            int br = input.nextInt();

            if (br == 1) {
                A = A - 1;
            }
            if (br == 2) {
                A = A - 2;
            } else {
                A = A - 3;
            }
        }
        Used same if statements for B & C then repeated all and just switched player.

        System.out.println("  A: " + A + "  B: " + B + "  C: " + C);

        System.out.println(player2 + " choose a pile:");

        String choose2 = x.nextLine();

        if (choose2.equals("A")) {
            System.out.println("How many to remove from pile A:");

            int br = input.nextInt();

            if (br == 1) {
                A = A - 1;
            }
            if (br == 2) {
                A = A - 2;
            } else {
                A = A - 3;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("  A: " + A + "  B: " + B + "  C: " + C);
    } while (A != 0 || B != 0 || C != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if is wrong, because will enter in your else condition if you chose `1`

This error is happening because you are using the same scanner that is alredy used, soo only the first iteration will work.

One way of solving this problem is initializate the scanner in every iteration

Something like this inside your Do While:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String choose = sc.nextLine();
```

And for the second one:

```
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
String choose2 = sc2.nextLine();
```

Comment: Ty, for this. I knew it was something simple :). I still need to declare a winner of the game. Want to do it in if statement but idk how to formulate condition.

Comment: And what's the condition for have a winning player?